# The content doesn't appears when I return to the previous activity

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app, which about writing notes. When I press the Edit button in **Second2** Activity it will move to the **Second3** Activity without any problems (In **Second3** Activity I can edit the note without any problem). But when I press the Save button, it will return to **Second2** but nothing appears there! It's just an empty Activity! Help me, please!

**MainActivity class:**

```
package com.twitter.i_droidi.mynotes;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView lv;
    NotesDataSource nDS;
    List<NotesModel> notesList;
    String[] notes;
    int i;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    AdView mAdView;
    AdRequest adRequest;
    public static long back_pressed;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nDS = new NotesDataSource(this);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

        nDS.open();
        notesList = nDS.getAllNotes();
        nDS.close();

        notes = new String[notesList.size()];

        for (i = 0; i < notesList.size(); i++) {
            notes[i] = notesList.get(i).getTitle();
        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1, notes);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        registerForContextMenu(lv);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) super.onBackPressed();
        else Toast.makeText(this, "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent nView = new Intent(this, Second2.class);
        nView.putExtra("id", notesList.get(position).getId());
        nView.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(nView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_delete, menu);
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.delete:
                AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                nDS.open();
                nDS.deleteNote(notesList.get(info.position).getId());
                notesList = nDS.getAllNotes();
                nDS.close();

                notes = new String[notesList.size()];

                for (i = 0; i < notesList.size(); i++) {
                    notes[i] = notesList.get(i).getTitle();
                }

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        android.R.id.text1, notes);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                registerForContextMenu(lv);
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

                Toast nDelete = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.deleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                nDelete.show();
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mainMenuNewNote:
                Intent nNote = new Intent(this, Second.class);
                startActivity(nNote);
                return true;

            case R.id.mainMenuAbout:
                AlertDialog.Builder aboutDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                aboutDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.about_title));
                aboutDialog.setMessage(R.string.about_body);
                aboutDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.my_notes);
                aboutDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface aboutDialog, int witch) {
                        // Do Not Do Anything.
                    }
                });

                aboutDialog.show();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Second class:**

```
package com.twitter.i_droidi.mynotes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Second extends ActionBarActivity {

    NotesDataSource nDS;
    EditText noteTitle;
    EditText noteBody;
    int id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        Intent in = getIntent();
        id = in.getIntExtra("id", 0);

        noteTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note_title);
        noteBody = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note);
        nDS = new NotesDataSource(this);

        nDS.open();
        NotesModel note = nDS.getNote(id);
        nDS.close();

        noteTitle.setText(note.getTitle());
        noteBody.setText(note.getBody());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.secondMenuSave:
                if (!noteTitle.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !noteBody.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    nDS.open();
                    nDS.createNote(noteTitle.getText().toString(), noteBody.getText().toString());
                    nDS.close();
                    Toast nSave = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.saved, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    nSave.show();
                    Intent nView = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    nView.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(nView);
                } else {
                    Toast notSave = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.do_not_save, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    notSave.show();
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Second2 class:**

```
package com.twitter.i_droidi.mynotes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Second2 extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView viewNoteTitle;
    TextView viewNoteBody;
    int id;
    NotesDataSource nDS;
    NotesModel note;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second2);

        Intent in = getIntent();
        id = in.getIntExtra("id", 0);

        viewNoteTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_note_title);
        viewNoteBody = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_note);
        nDS = new NotesDataSource(this);

        nDS.open();
        note = nDS.getNote(id);
        nDS.close();

        viewNoteTitle.setText(note.getTitle());
        viewNoteBody.setText(note.getBody());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_second2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.second2MenuEdit:
                Intent nEdit = new Intent(this, Second3.class);
                nEdit.putExtra("id", note.getId());
                nEdit.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(nEdit);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Second3 class:**

```
package com.twitter.i_droidi.mynotes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Second3 extends ActionBarActivity {

    NotesDataSource nDS;
    EditText noteTitle;
    EditText noteBody;
    int id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        Intent in = getIntent();
        id = in.getIntExtra("id", 0);

        noteTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note_title);
        noteBody = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note);
        nDS = new NotesDataSource(this);

        nDS.open();
        NotesModel note = nDS.getNote(id);
        nDS.close();

        noteTitle.setText(note.getTitle());
        noteBody.setText(note.getBody());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.secondMenuSave:
                if (!noteTitle.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !noteBody.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    nDS.open();
                    nDS.updateNote(id, noteTitle.getText().toString(), noteBody.getText().toString());
                    nDS.close();
                    Toast nSave = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.saved, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    nSave.show();
                    Intent nView = new Intent(this, Second2.class);
                    nView.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(nView);
                } else {
                    Toast notSave = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.do_not_save, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    notSave.show();
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is there in second2 activity initially?

Comment: The content of the note (Title and Body).

Comment: try to set the text in `onResume()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Second Activity gets data from Intent from these two lines:

```
Intent in = getIntent();
id = in.getIntExtra("id", 0);
```

So when you go back to this Activity from Third Activity that is when you save your note in the following lines:

```
Intent nView = new Intent(this, Second2.class);
nView.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(nView);
```

You have to add the id into the Intent as you did in the Main Activity class, you might do it as below, but you dont have the `noteList` array in the third activity.

```
nView.putExtra("id", notesList.get(position).getId());
```

So the easiest way to get the data in the activity is to call

`finish();`

This is because the Second Activity is still in the Activity Stack and you dont have to start it again, you can just finish the Third Activity and the Second will just show up because its the last Activity in the stack. But the title wont be updated so you'll have to start the Activity from beginning like the code below:

When you are done saving the note.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.secondMenuSave:
                if (!noteTitle.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !noteBody.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    nDS.open();
                    nDS.updateNote(id, noteTitle.getText().toString(), noteBody.getText().toString());
                    nDS.close();
                    Toast nSave = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.saved, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    nSave.show();
                    Intent nView = new Intent(this, Second2.class);
                    nView.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    nView.putExtra("id", id);

                    startActivity(nView);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast notSave = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.do_not_save, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    notSave.show();
                }
                return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

For you hopefully last problem, In the Second Activity override the onBackPressed method and add the code below:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: There is a problem! The Title and The Body of the note still the same after edit the note! Still the same in the Second3 and MainActivity!

Comment: right, apart from the finish(); you'll have to add the id to the Intent before startActivity(nView); , which i stated in the second paragraph of code

Comment: @MrGlitch I edited my answer copy and paste the last part of code, the onOptionsItemSelected method

Comment: Thanks! The main problem has been solved! But there is another problem, after editing the note, it updated in Second2 Activity, but in MainActivity still the same (as before edit it). I must close the app and return to it, to refresh the note to the new title in MainActivity!

Comment: hahaha okay so I'll just fix all of your code :), let me check wait a second.

Comment: @MrGlitch check the last part of code, Im assuming that your are going back to the MainActivity when pressing the back button, so you'll just have to start the MainActivity from scratch, you could do this with onResume, but i chose the easy way.

Comment: Thanks, man for helping me. Look at `onBackPressed()`, it will create many calls to the MainActivity, it means when I press back it will return to the MainActivity then when I press back again to close the app, it will return to the MainActivity again! After press back many times, it closes the app.

Comment: Don't worry, I will mark it as the correct answer! becuse it helps me a lot! :D

Comment: Thank you it was nice helping you

Comment: You are welcome! But wait xD.. there is a problem which related to your solution, can you help me with it?! Here in this replay "Thanks, man for helping me. Look at onBackPressed(), it will create many calls to the MainActivity, it means when I press back it will return to the MainActivity then when I press back again to close the app, it will return to the MainActivity again! After press back many times, it closes the app."

Comment: I edited my answer check the last part of code I added intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); this line of code